# Computation of centrifugal and Coriolis matrix

Tags: matlab, dynamics, force

So I have a [seesaw-cart electromechanical system](https://d3i71xaburhd42.cloudfront.net/67311e58bd203f6aee26dfa009a00ca896c71a50/2-Figure4-1.png) which I want to control. It has 2-DOF (the angle of the seesaw $\varphi$ and the cart position $s$).
I used the Euler-Lagrange method to get my equations of motion, which are as follows:

$$(J+m_Bb^2+m_Cc^2+m_Cs^2)\ddot\varphi - m_Cc\ddot{s} + \kappa\dot\varphi - g(m_Aa + m_Bb)sin(\varphi) + gm_C(s*cos(\varphi) - c*sin(\varphi)) = 0$$

$$m_C\ddot{s} + \frac{K_eK_t}{R_ap^2r^2}\dot{s} - m_Cc\ddot\varphi - m_Cs\dot\varphi^2 + m_Cgsin(\varphi) = \frac{K_t}{R_apr}U_a$$

Obviously, this is a non-linear problem which needs to be linearized so I can rewrite this into state-space form. Before I do that though I want to simplify my equations by writing them in the "infamous" dynamic equation:

$$M(q)\ddot{q}+C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+g(q)+\phi\dot{q}=E_MU_a$$

where $M$ is my inertia matrix, $C$ is my centrifugal and Coriolis matrix, $g$ is my gravitational vector, $\phi$ represents the viscous dampng term in my rotational joint and $E_M$ would (in my case) be the unit vector.

I got $M$, $g$, $\phi$ and $E_M$:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}J+m_Bb^2+m_Cc^2+m_Cs^2&-m_Cc\\-m_Cc&m_C\end{bmatrix},$$
$$g=\begin{bmatrix}-gsin(\varphi)(am_A+bm_B)+gm_C(s*cos(\varphi)-c*sin(\varphi))\\m_Cgsin(\varphi)\end{bmatrix},$$
$$\phi=\begin{bmatrix}\kappa&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},$$
$$E_M=\begin{bmatrix}0\\\frac{K_t}{R_apr}U_a\end{bmatrix}.$$

All that is left is the $C$ matrix. Based on online searches I found that the following **could** be my answer:

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}m_Cs\dot{s}&m_Cs\dot{\varphi}\\-m_Cs\dot{\varphi}&\frac{K_eK_t}{R_ap^2r^2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Can anyone check if this is correct? I would greatly appreciate it :)